# Estimating Lambda in a Poisson population where not all samples can be observed

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, estimation

Let $(x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n)$ be a random sample from a population which follows a Poisson distribution with an unknown mean $\lambda$. If we assume that $C$ is a known constant and we can only observe the values of the sample for which $x_i < C$.
I want to try to estimate $\lambda$ by only using these samples.

I first define two variables, $r$ and $p$, which can be defined as:

$$r = max(i: x_{(i)} < C)$$
$$p = max(i: x_{(i)} \le C-2)$$, where $x_{(i)}$ denotes the $i$th order statistic. I assume for convenience that $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p,\dots, x_r$ are the observed samples so they are ordered.

So if $X$ is a Poisson distributed random variable with density function $p(x)$, mean $\lambda$ and $C$ as being any constant, then

$$\lambda = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\space x\space p(x)$$

can be split up to $$\lambda = \sum_{x=C}^{\infty}\space x\space p(x) + \sum_{x=0}^{C-1}\space x\space p(x)$$

I can calculate the first part directly:
$$\sum_{x=C}^{\infty}\space x\space p(x) = \lambda(1-F(C-2))$$, where $F(.)$ is the CDF of the Poisson distribution.

An estimation of the second part would be:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^r x_i$$ and if $\bar{x_r}$ is the mean of the first $r$ observations, we can write this as:

$$\frac{r}{n} \bar{x_r}$$

Now, we could estimate $F(C-2)$ as $\frac{p}{n}$

So combining the terms and working out for $\lambda$, I get:

$$\lambda = \frac{r\bar{x_r}}{p}$$

This seems to be a good estimator, but when $C$ becomes very small compared against the real mean, the estimation loses accuracy.

The reason seems to be that estimating $F(C-2)$ from the observed samples isn't that accurate when $C$ gets small compared to $\lambda$, even if I use a large sample size (>100K).

So the questions I'm thinking about:

- Is there a more accurate way to estimate $F(C-2)$?
- Or maybe there ís something wrong with the math? In which case, please point out.
- Or maybe there is an easier way to estimate $\lambda$ from limited observed samples?

**EDIT**

I want to expand a bit based on the comments.

We can also say that $X$ follows a truncated Poisson distribution conditional on the event that $X < C$ with a known $C$, which is the truncation level.

If I read from the definition then I can write the PMF of a C-truncated Poisson distribution as $$\frac{p(x)}{F(C-1)}$$

If I then work out the log-likelihood function for $\lambda$, given the samples $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p, \dots, x_r$, I get:

$$L(\lambda|x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p, \dots, x_r) = \log(\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^r x_i - r\log(\sum_{i=0}^{C-1} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}) $$

Maximizing this function in $\lambda$ indeed gives me a good estimation for $\lambda$, but it seems that we always need a numerical method for it. If someone can elaborate more from this perspective, this is always welcome as well.

Comment: Can you estimate $\lambda$ using the MLE?

Comment: For the MLE, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/177348/8030) might be useful, although it assumes *unknown* truncation level.

Comment: When $C$ becomes very small, that means you got a lots of $0, 1$ etc, so the accuracy is low naturally. MLE is possible as you can use the truncated likelihood function, but you may need a numerical method for that

Comment: The PMF of the $r$ independent observations is $\frac{p_\lambda(x_1)}{F_{\lambda}(C-1)}\frac{p_\lambda(x_2)}{F_{\lambda}(C-1)}\cdots\frac{p_\lambda(x_r)}{F_{\lambda}(C-1)}\propto e^{-r\lambda}\lambda^{\sum x_i} [F_{\lambda}(C-1)]^{-r}.$ Your $L$ should be the *log* of this, so you've omitted the term "$-r\lambda$". Also note that in the link I gave, the *initial estimate* for computing the MLE numerically is exactly your estimator, except their $k(=C-1)$ is assumed unknown and so is estimated by $\max(x_1,...,x_r)$.

Comment: As explained in my previous comment: What your latest edit calls $L$ is not the likelihood function, but is rather the *log-likelihood* function for $\lambda,$ except you've omitted the term "$-r\lambda$". If you add this term to your $L$, you get the same log-likelihood used in the link I gave; also, note that they cite Moore (1952, Biometrika) as a source for what is essentially your estimator.

Comment: @r.e.s. indeed, it was the log likelihood (my mistake, it was a typo). If I do the math, the term $-r\lambda$ is always omitted, so there must be a key difference between the link and my post. But more interestingly: how is the estimator of Moore, 1952 the same as my estimator $$\lambda = \frac{r\bar{x_r}}{p}$$ ? I don't directly see it...

Comment: My earlier comment shows how $e^{-r\lambda}$ is in the likelihood func., so ${-r\lambda}$ is in the log-likelihood. Since this term depends on $\lambda$, it cannot be omitted. E.g., see the log-lik. shown in the link I gave. Also at that link, their initial estimator is $\hat{\lambda}_0 ={{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}\over{\sum_{i=1}^n I(y_i<\hat{k})}}.$ Changing to your symbols, and putting $\hat k=C-1$ (because in your case $k=C-1$ is known), this becomes ${{\sum_{i=1}^r x_i}\over{\sum_{i=1}^r I(x_i<C-1)}}={{\sum_{i=1}^r x_i}\over\text{#obs. less than $(C-1)$}}={r\bar x_r\over p}.$

Comment: But isn't $e^{-r\lambda}$ omitted because of  $ e^{-\lambda} $ in $F(C-1)$ ? $F(C-1) = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{c-1} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}$

Comment: Oops, sorry -- yes, I misread what you've done with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the MLE derivation:

We have underlying r.v.s $X_1,X_2,\dots$ i.i.d $\text{Poisson($\lambda$)}$, but we only observe those $X_i$ for which $X_i\le k$ (letting $k=C-1$ for convenience). To better distinguish the observations from the possibly-unobserved r.v.s, I'll write the observations (say $r$ of them) as $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_r.$

The joint PMF of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_r$ is therefore

$$\begin{align}P(Y_1=y_1,...,Y_r=y_r)
&=\prod_{i=1}^rP(Y_i=y_i)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^rP(X_{j_i}=y_i\mid X_{j_i}\le k)\quad\text{for the corresponding $X_{j_i}$}\\[1ex]
&=\prod_{i=1}^r{P(X_{j_i}=y_i)\over P(X_{j_i}\le k)}\\[1ex]
&=\prod_{i=1}^r{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{y_i}/y_i!\over F_\lambda(k)}\\[1ex]
&\propto e^{-r\lambda}\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^ry_i}[F_\lambda(k)]^{-r}\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$

where $F_\lambda$ is the $\text{Poisson($\lambda$)}$ CDF. The log-likelihood function is therefore

$$-r\lambda +\left(\sum_{i=1}^ry_i\right)\log\lambda - r \log F_\lambda(k)\tag{1}$$

which is another way of writing the expression you wrote in your latest edit.

The MLE for $\lambda$ is then the value $\hat\lambda$ that maximizes (1), given the observations and the known value $k.$ [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/177348/8030) lists an R-program that accomplishes this numerically in the case *when $k$ is unknown*, using (in the present notation)

$$\hat{\lambda}_0 ={{\sum_{i=1}^r y_i}\over{\sum_{i=1}^r I(y_i<\hat{k})}}={\sum_{i=1}^r y_i\over\text{number of observations less than $\hat k$}}
$$

as the starting value, where $\hat k=\max(y_1,...y_r)$ is an estimate of $k$. (They cite Moore (1952, Biometrika) for this.) Note that if the estimate $\hat k$ is replaced by our *known value* $k$, then this *initial estimate* $\hat \lambda_0$ is precisely the estimate you've proposed, i.e. ${r \bar y_r\over\text{number of observations less than $k$}}={r \bar y_r\over p}.$

---

Based on $10^5$ Monte Carlo trials with $\lambda=10,$ $k\in\{5,8,10,12,15\}$, and $r\in\{25, 50, 100\},$ it appears that $\hat\lambda_0$ has less bias but slightly more sampling variance that does the MLE. (I simply adapted the linked R program to the case of known $k$.) Here are typical results for $\lambda=10, r=50, k=5:$

[image: histograms for lambda_0 and lambda_MLE]

This case: $\text{est.}\mathbb E(\hat\lambda_0)=10.3$, $\text{est.}\sigma(\hat\lambda_0)=2.1,\quad$ $\text{est.}\mathbb E(\hat\lambda_{MLE})=10.7,$ $\text{est.}\sigma(\hat\lambda_{MLE})=2.0.$

Comment: Thanks! But in my derivation I use $$\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{y_i}}{y_{i}!}}{F_{\lambda}(k)} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{y_i}}{y_{i}!e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}} =  \frac{\lambda^{y_i}}{y_{i}!\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}}$$, so how is my derivation incorrect?

Comment: @Steven01123581321 Sorry, my mistake! I misread how you rewrote this expression.

Comment: oh okay!:) and +1 your answer for the interesting observation that my estimator is the same as that of Moore, 1952 and the simulation results! Leaving the space for other answers as well, so for the moment I did not accept it as a final answer (yet)